# Nextjs Web app showing "untitled" in google search

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, next.js, seo, devops

I have deployed a nextjs web app in aws with ssl certificate added. It's working fine when I browse directly to the app. But, when I search it in the google, it showing **"untitled"**,
**"javascript not enabled"** and showing **http instead of https**.

[image]

I'm sure I have added the title and all meta tags. I'm using next/image for render image. Is it will be the issue?

Comment: Use the head component from the next/head package to specify a title for your page.

Comment: I've already added it. Still not working

Comment: I had the problem with Whatsapp and I solved it yesterday, I understand why it's happening. So I was looking for other people having the same problem to help. I'll post a solution soon, but if you still want it I'll try to post it faster. The tip is to send the tags info direct to `_app.js` on server side and get them via `props.pageProps` and add them inside Head like `<><Head>...</Head><Provider><Component /></Provider></>` outside of any component that will trigger javascript to rendre. This way `_app.js` will sen the head info directly in HTML code, ready for facebook, whatsapp, Google.

Comment: The issue fixed. There was a old cache on the google crawler. We request to google crawl again and issue fixed. Thankyou